# Do you know any 3D engines written in Objective-C for iOS?

Tags: objective-c

In the next few weeks I will start a game for iOS, most of the action will happen in 2D but a 2D engine is not enough for our idea, therefore I'm doing a small research on available 3D engines for iOS written in Objective-C (we already looked on some engines written in C++).

 
Do you know 3D engines written in Objective-C?

I found this one http://nineveh.gl/ but is not yet ready :(.

**later edit (1)**.......
I did a research on the engines written in C++, they are nice and probably I will go with one of them, but if there is any good engine written in Objective-C, than I will go with it, because its a matter of taste and I like very much the obj-c language.


**later edit (2)**.......
nice presentation/teaser about what I'm looking for http://www.slideshare.net/rsebbe/designing-an-objectivec-framework-about-3d

Comment: Why does it have to be in Obj-C?  What was wrong with the C++ engines?

Comment: My guess is he wants to program his app in Objective-C, and thus the actual engine language doesn't matter.

Comment: Its nothing wrong with C++. But I like more Objective-C, and if I can have an engine which at least has a good objective-c api wrapper than I will go with it.

Comment: you might want to select an answer to encourage people answer your questions in future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also want to check out iSGL3D (http://isgl3d.com) which is an open source Objective-C iOS scene graph library.

It works with both OpenGL ES 1.1 and ES 2.0 with a number of features such as simple scene and object manipulation, lighting and shading, cameras, multiple views, meshes and particles, tweening, mesh skinning, vertex animation, shadows, object interactivity, etc.

It uses a few C++ hooks for external libraries such as Bullet physics and PowerVR POD importing but these are wrapped in Objective-C classes.

Comment: I had to choose between ISGL3D and Cocos3D, I went with latter because there was more response in the official forum.

Answer (score 4):

Cocos3d is an extension for Cocos2d and supports many features. Check out their website - 
http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/

Comment: This looks to be the best answer to the question, but I'm wondering the same thing as tetrad; why not c++?

Comment: I knew about it, I hardly wait for the May release which is said to have touch controls on the models :D.

@Jhocking, check out my edit

Comment: Even thought I knew about Cocos3d, until now, it seems to be the only framework to do what I want, but still I have to wait for the May release... that's why I chose this answer :)

Comment: Cocos3D is good.. You can easily export models from 3D editors, you have default 2D physics engine. You can easily port bullet 3D physics engine. Looks very good.

Answer (score 0):

Check out both the Unreal Development Kit (http://www.udk.com/) and Unity (http://www.unity3d.com) engines.  Both have Objective-C hooks.

I am assuming that it's not important that the engine itself be written in Objective-C, only that you can program in Objective-C and use the engine.

Comment: That would also qualify any C++ engine then..

Comment: True.  I listed Unreal and Unity as they are both top notch professional engines that are well supported and accepted.

Answer (score 0):

[Galaxy Engine](http://code.google.com/p/galaxyengine/) looks pretty solid. It's not just a 3D engine written in Objective-C, but the package also contains scene manager, mesh converter and dozen of other content-creation related tools.

Also check out the [Oolong engine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/), it's mostly written in C++ and maintained by Wolfgang Engel of Rockstar Games fame.

Comment: Galaxy Looks nice, but I didn't manage to compile it, watched the youtube video on how to do it, it failed and I didn't bother to go further, I will give it another try this weekend.